# C# fill Dynamic Grid with TextBox, Button and more in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, uniformgrid

- VS2010 -C#
  I have a TextBox where you can input an integer and a UniformGrid is dynamically generated with the integer number of UniformGrid Cells. Now if I want to add a TextBox to each UniformGrid Cell, I do the following (e.g. int is a 5):

> TextBox[] tb = new TextBox[5];
>    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
>               {
>                   tb[i] = new Textbox();
>                   UniformGrid1.Children.Add(tb[i]);
>               }

Ok..that works fine.  But problem comes when I need also to fill in some more Texboxes, Buttons, and Labels in it with some design properties defined, possibly also insert a grid inside a UniformGrid Cell. It will get extremely messy if I create arrays for each control and define each array properties in the loop.
Not only that it's messy, I cannot put the textbox inside the UniformGrid's Cell's Grid. The children add the grid on top of the TextBox instead.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using specialized controls like [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) would be better, beacuse it automatically creates two-way bindings to model, it's easy to maintain, etc. There are lots of examples, for example [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) (Google can help you to find more, if you ask something like "wpf datagrid example tutorial")

Answer (score 2):

You should use DataBinding instead.

Make a ItemsControl bind it to ObservableCollection and use UniformGrid as a container to ItemsControl.